Linearity Proof for Integral of Simple functions over general measures
Definition: Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\psi$ a nonnegative simple function on $X$. Define the integral of $\psi$ over $X$, $\int_X\psi d\mu$, as follows: if $\psi=0$ on $X$, define $\int_X\psi d_\mu=0$. Otherwise, let $c_1,c_2,...,c_m$ be the positive values taken by $\psi$ on $X$, and, for $1\leq k\leq n$, define $E_k=\{x\in X:\psi(x)=c_k\}$. Define
$$ \int_X\psi d\mu=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\cdot \mu(E_k)$$.
Proposition:
Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\phi$ and $\psi$ nonnegative simple function on $X$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive real numbers, then
$$ \int_X[\alpha \psi +\beta \phi]d\mu=\alpha \int_X \psi d\mu +\beta \int_X \phi d\mu $$.
Proof (book of Royden):
If either $\psi$ or $\phi$ is positive on a set of infinite measure, then the linear combination $\alpha \cdot \psi +\beta \cdot \phi$ has the same property and therefore each side of the equation is infinite. We therefore, assume both $\psi$ and $\phi$ vanish outside a set of finite measure and hence so does the linear combination $\alpha \cdot \psi +\beta \cdot \phi$. In this case the proof is exactly the same as the proof for Lebesgue integration of functions of a real variable.
My question is why is the case where $\psi$ or $\phi$ is nonnegative on a set of infinite measure not considered? why only consider $\psi$ or $\phi$ is positive on a set of infinite measure?

$\int \phi d\mu$ can be $0$ if $\phi$ is non-negative on a set of infinite measure. Example, $\phi \equiv 0$.

Because $\psi$ a linear combination of indicator functions. We can ignore the parts that are zero.

Thank you, but how about if the set of x in X where $\phi(x)=0$ has infinite measure while all other subset of X where $\phi$ is positive has finite measure?

I believe the convention is $0\cdot\infty=0$ in this case. You are asking what the area of a ray is, well it has no positive "height" so the area is zero.

That would mean that the integral now would be finite right?
